# SoftKeyboard Preview key Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-softkeyboard

[Preview Key Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfDEz.png)

Please check the image and tell me what i'm doing wrong. I'm working on softkeyboard application. Preview key is not fully displaying on top keyboard row. I get the softkeyboard code from google Latin keyboard repository.

Here is the code for Keyboard.

```
    <com.unclekeyboard.arabic.android.LatinKeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:keyBackground="@drawable/key_preview_state"
    android:keyPreviewHeight="60dp"
    android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/key_preview_layout"
    android:keyTextColor="#FFF"
    android:keyTextSize="20sp"
    android:labelTextSize="18sp">

</com.unclekeyboard.arabic.android.LatinKeyboardView>
```

Let me know what else should i provide.

Comment: Can you post your keyboard displaying code?

Comment: I've added the code now.